# dynamic column length, same width

Tags: html, css

i have a situation

I add a pictures of what I need to accomplish.

Does  anyone know how to solve this issue - when having different length of the columns to make others to stay in their position?

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 align-items-stretch box-spacing mt-4 mt-md-0" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="profile-box">Category number one</h5>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
              <h6 class="h-question">Q1 lalala</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
              <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
                aliqua.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
              <h6 class="h-question">Q2 lalala</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
              <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
              <a href="#"><span class="edit">Edit</span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-1">
              <a href="#"><span class="print-icon"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-1">
              <a href="#"><span class="print-icon"><i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i></span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-8">
              <a href="#">
                <h6 class="text-right">Show More <span class="q-arrow"><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-down"></i></span></h6>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 align-items-stretch box-spacing mt-4 mt-md-0" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="profile-box">Category number two</h5>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
              <h6 class="h-question">Q1 lalala</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
              <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
              <h6 class="h-question">Q2 lalala</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
              <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
              <a href="#"><span class="edit">Edit</span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-1">
              <a href="#"><span class="print-icon"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-1">
              <a href="#"><span class="print-icon"><i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i></span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-8">
              <a href="#">
                <h6 class="text-right">Show More <span class="q-arrow"><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-down"></i></span></h6>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 align-items-stretch box-spacing mt-4 mt-md-0" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="profile-box">Category number three</h5>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
              <h6 class="h-question">Q1 lalala</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
              <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
              <h6 class="h-question">Q2 lalala</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
              <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
              <a href="#"><span class="edit">Edit</span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-1">
              <a href="#"><span class="print-icon"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-1">
              <a href="#"><span class="print-icon"><i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i></span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-8">
              <a href="#">
                <h6 class="text-right">Show More <span class="q-arrow"><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-down"></i></span></h6>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 align-items-stretch box-spacing mt-4 mt-md-0" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="profile-box">Category number four</h5>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
              <h6 class="h-question">Q1 lalala</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
              <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
              <h6 class="h-question">Q2 lalala</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
              <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
              <a href="#"><span class="edit">Edit</span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-1">
              <a href="#"><span class="print-icon"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-1">
              <a href="#"><span class="print-icon"><i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i></span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-8">
              <a href="#">
                <h6 class="text-right">Show More <span class="q-arrow"><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-down"></i></span></h6>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 align-items-stretch box-spacing mt-4 mt-md-0" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="profile-box">Category number five</h5>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
              <h6 class="h-question">Q1 lalala</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
              <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
              <h6 class="h-question">Q2 lalala</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
              <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
              <a href="#"><span class="edit">Edit</span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-1">
              <a href="#"><span class="print-icon"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-1">
              <a href="#"><span class="print-icon"><i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i></span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-8">
              <a href="#">
                <h6 class="text-right">Show More <span class="q-arrow"><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-down"></i></span></h6>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 align-items-stretch box-spacing mt-4 mt-md-0" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="profile-box">Category number six</h5>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
              <h6 class="h-question">Q1 lalala</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
              <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
              <h6 class="h-question">Q2 lalala</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
              <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
              <a href="#"><span class="edit">Edit</span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-1">
              <a href="#"><span class="print-icon"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-1">
              <a href="#"><span class="print-icon"><i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i></span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-8">
              <a href="#">
                <h6 class="text-right">Show More <span class="q-arrow"><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-down"></i></span></h6>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: first fix you HTML spacings and push them with CSS into a parsable snippet. Then actually add the image which is not added to your post.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this. Can you use JS to know how many items each column has? do you always want the top-most item to have double-height in case you have just 3 items in a column? what is there's only 2 items? 1?